# Straightening Jagged/Pixelated Edges

Tags: image-processing

Suppose I have a simple black and white image with some pixelated edges, and I want to make them look clean and straight. I have attached an example of what I mean. I want to make all the edges straight instead of having the pixellated, "sawtooth" look to them. What is the easiest way to go about doing this, short of going in and editing pixel by pixel with paintbrush (which would be difficult to do, without breaking the tessellation and without making the shapes non-uniform)? The image is jagged because it is based on a low-resolution image I got off the internet. [image: Tessellation]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First idea: apply a Gaussian blur filter and binarize the image. This will soften the sharp angles a little, but is easy to implement.

[image]